# I am trying to get the time difference between the execution of 2 commands, one is !on and the other !off (Discord.JS))

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following code. It works to an extent, but when I do the !off command, it shows me a 0 instead of the actual time difference.

**Index Code**

```
global.time = getDateTime()
global.oldTime = getNewDateTime().getTime
global.finalTime = parseFloat(time) - parseFloat(oldTime)

function getDateTime() {

  var date = new Date();

  var hour = date.getHours();
  hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;

  var min  = date.getMinutes();
  min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

  var sec  = date.getSeconds();
  sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

  return hour + ":" + min;
}`` 
console.log(parseFloat(getDateTime))

function getNewDateTime() {

  var date = new Date();

  var hour = date.getHours();
  hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;

  var min  = date.getMinutes();
  min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

  var sec  = date.getSeconds();
  sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

  return hour + ":" + min;
 
}
```

And here is the off command, same with on almost

```
 exports.run = async (client, message, args, tools) => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("BLUE")

      .addField("Timer ended. Total Time Online", `**: ${finalTime}**`)
message.channel.send(embed);
}
```